# Menu com blocos lado a lado, um fixo e outro fluido

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Como faço com que um menu horizontal tenha de um lado com largura fluida e o outro com largura fixa?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O menu não será fixo no topo e precisa funcionar na maioria dos browsers(isso pq não posso usar o calc do css).

Estou usando o bootstrap.

Comment: você ja utilizou container-fluid  e container? tem alguma demo em html?

Comment: O problema é a div que fica fixa logo ao lado de uma fluida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algo assim?

```css
.bg-dinamico{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: blue;
    margin:0px!important;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row bg-dinamico">
  <div style="background:blue">Fluid</div>
  <div style="width:200px;background:red">Estatic</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um modelo bem simples mesmo, olha se te atende.

A `div` que fica a esquerda não tem tamanho, porém *tem uma margem a direita que é do tamanho da div que fica a direita*. Dessa forma eu fiz o "calc" apenas descontando com a margem o tamanho da outra `div`.

Seria assim: `<div>` da esquerda com 100% de largura por ser um elemento **block** e margin-right:200px e uma `<div>` a direita com 200px de largura e `floar:right`

Olha o código que vc vai entender, fiz do jeito mais simples possível.

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
}
.cont::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}
.dir {
    background-color: aqua; 
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.esq {
    background-color: black;
    height: 80px;
    margin-right: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <div class="dir"></div>
    <div class="esq"></div>
</div>
```

> Também fiz o `::after` no container das `divs` com `clear:both;` para não sobrepor nas `divs` que vierem abaixo.